# How can I index individual items via an API call to Infinispan or Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search, infinispan

I have an application which uses Hibernate Search (backed by Lucene indexes) and Infinispan. I do *not*  use Hibernate Core to load my data (this should be fine since 3.2 I believe).

On start-up the application loads a lot of data into Infinispan caches from various sources. I found that if we left automatic indexing (i.e. *not* specifying hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual) that the cache inserts (and associated indexing) used a lot of memory and would often not finish at all. To fix this I disabled automatic indexing, and after inserting all the initial data run a bulk/mass indexer on the cache - this takes just a few seconds and works fine.

My problem is that I periodically insert/update/delete items from the caches, and I cannot find a way to tell either Infinispan or Hibernate Search to [re-]index these items. The closest I can find from the [Hibernate Search Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.1/reference/en/html/search-batchindex.html) involves a Hibernate session, and would only work on managed objects. I do not load data via Hibernate so this is not possible.

**How can I index individual items via an API call to Infinispan or Hibernate Search?**

I look forward to any help you can provide, a let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infinispan does not provide an explicit index() method. It's a good idea to add one, you're welcome to open a JIRA as a feature request.

What you can do is to keep automatic indexing enabled at all times, but then disable indexing on each put() operation using [the withFlags method on AdvancedCache](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/6.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/AdvancedCache.html#withFlags%28org.infinispan.context.Flag...%29) and enable the Flag [SKIP_INDEXING](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/6.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/context/Flag.html#SKIP_INDEXING).

```
Cache nonIndexedCache = cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(Flag.SKIP_INDEX);
nonIndexedCache.put( ... );
```

Note that the first line in the example is rather slow, so you want to keep the reference to that cache to do multiple put operations.

Comment: That's perfect, I love you.